# Where does the & stand for in this query

Tags: mysql, sign

I have a simple question,

In some old code I came up a query containing:

`WHERE !(workassignment.flags&1)`

I have never seen the & sign used in a query before.

It is clear what the query does to me but what is & sign and why would I use this in a query.

Comment: Bitwise AND: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and

Comment: AFAIK, `&` in SQL does bitwise `AND`ing of values and checks for least significant bit being set or not, which inherently means to check if value is even or odd. Why would you use it would be a guess on our part, but it seems that `WHERE` clause would look for records other than current `flags` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The & stands for a bitwise AND operation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND). A bitwise and on the value 1 (which is what the WHERE statement uses) will return 1 when the rightmost bit in `workassignment.flags` is set to 1, and otherwise will return 0.

So `1 & 1` = 1 and `0 & 1` = 0.

Comment: Oke that makes sense I understand now

Answer (score 1):

It's a "bitwise AND" test - it's looking to see if the least significant bit of `workassignment.flags` is (not) set.